# Proving $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, predicate-logic

Is this correct formal way to prove
$A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ ?

$$ \begin{split} 
x \in A \cap \emptyset  & \iff x \in  \Big[x \ | \ (x \in A) \land (x \in \emptyset)\Big] \\
& \iff (x \in A) \land (x \in \emptyset) \\
& \iff (x \in A) \land F \\
& \iff F \\
& \iff x \in \emptyset
\end{split}$$

Comment: The grammatical structure is off...  Try reading it aloud.  "*For every $x$ in $A\cap \emptyset$ if and only if ... if and only if False if and only if Empty set*"

Comment: You are mixing the language of set th and its countrpart in predicate logic... You must have : $x \in A \cap \emptyset \Leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \in \emptyset)$

Comment: Having derived $\text F$, you can conclude that the assumption is False, and thus $\lnot (x \in A \cap \emptyset)$, for every $x$. This means that $A \cap \emptyset$ is the empty set.

Comment: $A\cap B$ is always a subset of $B$. If $B=\emptyset$ there aren't very many subsets available.

Comment: @JMoravitz so my derivation is wrong, right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I edited "for all" symbol which I borrowed from predicate calculus. I like to write it that way. So, I can connect logic and set theory :)

Comment: Its not "wrong" per se, just phrased poorly.  I would have had $\forall x$ outside of the entire logical chain of implications (*$\forall x$ the following implication chain holds... $x\in A\cap \emptyset \iff (x\in A \wedge x\in \emptyset)\iff \dots$*) and then later on for the final line I would have ended it with $x\in \emptyset$ as the final statement... not $\emptyset$ by itself.  (*$\dots \iff F\iff x\in \emptyset$*)

Comment: @JMoravitz does it look okay now? I just edited.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A \cap \emptyset \ne \emptyset$, so it exists an $x$ that belongs to $A \cap \emptyset$. But then $x \in \emptyset$ absurd.

Comment: Is my derivation wrong?

Comment: I think you are making things too formalized. The solution simply comes once you have understood what intersection and $\emptyset$ are.

Comment: I am learning. So, I have to be precise as much as possible. I am following Tremblay and Manohar book.

Comment: Precision does not always implies formalism. Sometimes in strict formalism you loose simplicity and the beauty of math.. unless you are a logician lol

Comment: I understand what you trying to convey, but I am learning and hopping to be good at mathematics in near future. That's why I am putting lots of efforts. Today, I took two pages to solve $A \subseteq B \iff A \cup B = B$ and I was quite satisfied the way I proved it with the use of my knowledge of inference rules of logic :) Also, thank you so much for providing your time. If you want to see I can click a pic and share in chat, if you like to see.

Comment: I think two pages are really too much for such a proposition, but this is only my opinion.

Comment: Check this here I uploaded [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/gmH3Env)